# Know when an Android app is moved to recent list

Tags: android, lifecycle

I would like to know if there's a way to know when an app goes from foreground to recent app list.

I need this because I want to save all the stuff before the user can swipe it away and kill it brutally

Comment: Ideally, you save as you go, because that's not the only way that your process can be terminated. FWIW, the closest thing to what you are seeking is `ProcessLifecycleOwner`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider any type of data into two categories

1. **Atomic**
2. **Semi-atomic**

First one being obvious, you only save it with consent of user.
Example -> payment-transfer, sending-text etc

Second is something little subjective, as you would like to save it as temporary information like half written message which user didn't  send which you can save temporarily ( given if user uninstalls the app this data won't be coming back -- but consider this with grain of salt as nobody will stop you from saving it remotely in cloud)

for android [OnPause()](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle#onpause) callback is a good place to save, However if you are working with some drawing app, let a Handler() trigger a save every few seconds.

Comment: onPause is the correct place i think. Unfortunately it happens that when it got killed, onPause kicks in, my app tries to save file but often the save file is corrupted because the app doesn't have enough time to complete the dump